# UITableView scroll to section within content size

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a table view with 3 sections, "Yesterday, Today, Tomorrow". When the table view launches I want the "Today" section to be the upper most visible section. Therefore I use this function:

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

This works fine when the table view is filled beyond its content size so it's scrollable. The problem is when for example each section contain only 1 cell. Then the whole table will fit on the screen, and therefore the above code will not fire since it would rubberband back anyway.

Anyone know of a solution to this?

Comment: Think you need to increase the content size of the tabel view to be able to scroll

Comment: Yes. The problem with that is that you will be able to scroll "too far", and the scroll indicators won't give a good visual on how much content there is...

Comment: yes that is right but from proper calculation you can adjust the content size that allows you to use you the above method with some conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering this myself since there aren't really any ideas.

From my understanding, this is impossible to achieve. The table view will try to scroll to the row if it can. Only way to make it work is to set the content size to be large enough for the table to scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the edgeInsets of the table.  This will start the drawing of the table by the offset you specify.

```
UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(someValue, 0, 0, 0);
self.tableView.contentInset = edgeInsets;
```

Where you calculate `someValue` to bring the table down to where you want it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried this and it only works on tables where the content is bigger than the actual table frame it seems. The tables that have smaller content (for example those with 3 cells) seem to completely ignore the edge insets.